# Missing Information In Thesis

Tags: thesis

My question is about my master thesis. In the term of my master career (about 1 year ago), i prepared conference papers and presentations which were not published but presented. And added those papers to my thesis and published it.

But nowadays, i realized that we didn't share the detailed informations about the model that i covered. I mean we shared the model as a pictures and informations but we didn't share in detail and without them, actually results and sentences are useless. On the other hand actually i think this is the most critical part; i realized that we didn't share how we handled the first step. We directly started from the next step and we presented results in thesis. And talked about them.

Actually question is; How did you get this graph = Missing for three graphs

The second one is what was the detailed properties of the model = Missing in thesis

On the other hand, if someone asks my detailed model i can of course share them and i can explain them in detail. But i revised some codes* that are used in my thesis and they have been changed and actually i may not produce the same graphs. 
*we didn't share codes in my thesis also

So, if someone take action about me for not to present some details in thesis and for not to explaining one step in thesis in terms of methodology, is it seen as an academic problem or serious sitation? Thanks in advance

EXTRA INFORMATION to clarify: My one chapter is based on that information. Without that missing information you can not reproduce figures and graphs. So, it effect the reproducibilty of my master thesis.

Comment: Just to clarify: how/where did you 'publish' your thesis? And have you graduated yet, and is this question "after the fact", or do you still need to defend your work and get your diploma?

Comment: Thank you for answer, i graduated from M.sc one year ago. And yes i got my diploma. And it is published in website of center the of universities of my country

Answer (score 2):

If your thesis was accepted and you have your degree, there is no "action" that can be taken against you. You can, however, produce a new publication giving the "missing" background of your original study.

Even better would be to extend your work, and maybe your model and explain in a new paper the new work, encompassing the old.

Just be careful to cite the old work, especially since it has been "published" on the website. That will probably make it impossible to republish that, but makes it even more possible to derive new work from it.

But any "blame" for missing parts is not yours alone, being shared with your advisor and any committee that accepted the work. But, in fact, I don't think there is really any blame to share. Move on. Do even better work.

Comment: Thank you, as i understand; it is acceptable to miss some steps of procedure explanations and also missing to share some details of design/model. As far as i can produce a new journal/conference paper etc?

Comment: could you look at question again, i revised the last sentence. I briefly explained that information

Comment: No change needed. If someone needs to reproduce it they will contact you. But think about writing that follow up paper.

Comment: Thank you. So, there is no reason for revoking of my M.Sc. licence?

Comment: Like Buffy, I would do an update paper and use that as a chance to explicitly update issues with the thesis. You can do this in a gentle fashion that still makes it clear that in some sense it is a correction.

P.s.  If your publication is in English, please upgrade your grammar.  The volume of miscapitalization and comma abuse made it hard to parse your content.  This isn't meant as a personal cut or to say that I am any better.